# Cannot connect via ssh to FiLab ubuntu instance

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, instance, pem, filab

I try with `ssh -i file.pem ubuntu@my-public-ip` and I get the `timeout` error. What I did before:

1. Create the instance on the FiLab panel
2. Add a floating ip
3. Create and add a keypair for remote access
4. Download de file.pem and give it 600 permissions
5. Look for the missing documentation
6. Send an email to tech support of FiLab who redirected me here

So, what's wrong?

List of commands I tried:

1. `ssh -i file.pem ubuntu@my-public-ip`
2. `ssh -i file.pem root@my-public-ip`
3. `sudo ssh -i file.pem my-public-ip`

Notice that when I ping the ip it throw the `request timeout` error but in the Cloud Portal what I see is:

- Status: Active
- Task: None
- Power State: Running

I have 3 machines and cannot access any of them.

**Edit:**

FiLab's Cloud Portal cannot connect neither to the machines. After more than hour awaiting I can confirm that it never resolves the loading event. Attached image:

[image]

Comment: Seems to be a firewall issue. Check if port 22 is open (somewhere in Cloud Portal, I guess, but I never used FiLab).

Comment: Also, is my-public-ip the IP of the instance or the IP of the computer you are connecting from? It should be the IP you added in step 2.

Comment: @suriv thanks for the reply. I'm connecting to the floating ip (step 2). Anyway, I try both just in case. And no one work. I look for the port configuration and I think I cannot fix that. Also, I discover that the Cloud Portal cannot connect neither to the machines; the VM Display never resolves the loading event. I edited the oc adding this.

Comment: @Deerloper can you see if you can do it now.

Comment: @flopez I was doing the changes and then another one trigger. I've just fixed with the help of Filab support. I'm pretty sure that tomorrow I'll test if it works ;) I'll edit this comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description of the problem, it seems that port 22 is firewalled. You need to create or edit a security group allowing TCP port 22, and assign it to the instance.

I found a [presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/flopezaguilar/setting-up-your-virtual-infrastructure-using-fi-lab-cloud-32388357) that explains how to do this (see slides 14-21).